# Create a automatically updating Excel table using MS Word inputs

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Is it possible to **use a one row table in MS-Word to enter rows in an Excel sheet**?

Both tables has the following rows

```
Name/ ID / City / Address /
```

Each time I open the word document and fill out the table, I want the data to be saved in the table in Excel, under the existing rows.

For instance if one day, I Opened the word file and entered

```
Peter / 1 / NY / 12 street.
```

Next day, I open the word file, deleted what I had before and enter

```
Steve/ 9 /CA/ 2 street.
```

Excel contain these rows

```
Peter / 1 / NY / 12 street.
Steve/ 9 /CA/ 2 street.
```

Excel pretty much works like a data storage for all the entries in *MS Word*.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of VBA? Have you tried anything yet? Perhaps even more crucially, why do you need to do it like this? Solutions are possible but this is not a 'write my code for me' website; it is likely you could find a solution that does what you want without even needing to code at all. Frankly I'm confused about why you would want to enter a single row of data in Word, just to have that single row transferred to Excel.

Comment: I asked for an advice not a code.

Comment: I'm asking this question because I wanted to learn vba if you don't like me asking these questions you can simply walk away and stop being a jerk

Comment: You might start with explaining yourself better. You would have more positive and to the point response.

Comment: You should consider doing it the other way around. Enter data into excel (or even better access) and create a word document (or perhaps an access report).. This would be a more conventional and possibly easier method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your code should go in the main `ThisWorkbook` module in a function `Private Sub Document_Close()`.

You will have to instantiate an Excel Application. Before you do that, add a reference to the `Microsoft Excel Object` library, using the `Tools` > `References` menu.

When you need to manipulate an Excel file from within Word, it is usually more practical to code your Excel manipulations in Excel-VBA first and then cut and paste them to your Word VBA project. You will have better support from code completion in Excel. You will however have to debug the code again and add a few things to make Word understand that you are working with Excel objects.

Now start googeling and have fun